# Need to get first child a and create a click event with the result

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to create a JavaScript program that looks through a DOM to find the first `<a href>` which is NOT a `mailto:` - it needs to be a 'real link' and return the `href` value. I then need the to create a `click` event with the result.

What I need it for is an HTML  encapsulating the author stuff of a post.
This needs to be clickable - but without using the `onclick` in the markup.
It needs to be an event - invisible in the HTML markup.

The wrapping `section` should also be clickable, but not be affected by whatever happens in what I described above.

Markup is this:

```
<section>
  <figure>
    <img>
  </figure>
  <div>
    <h2>
    <p>
      <a href="mailto:.."></a>
      <a href="THE VALUE I NEED"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

/* EDIT */

OK found this.

```
function (a){return typeof f!="undefined"&&(!a||f.event.triggered!==a.type)?f.event.dispatch.apply(i.elem,a‌​rguments):b}
```

This is the string i get in the Event window in FireBug from the site I'm trying to get this function from. Does anybody understand this? That string is what makes it work. I've just copied the entire js over and it works on my site, but I would like to isolate this particular function since the original file is huge. Anyone?

Comment: The question is not complete. Add own research, current JavaScript, etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LrgQH/

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var link, i;

for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    link = links[i];
    if (link.href.indexOf('mailto:') !== 0) {
        break;   
    }
}

link.onclick = function(e) {
   alert('allo');
}
```

Vanilla JS should work anywhere.

## Edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/LrgQH/2/

This should do it, and you'll have to prevent other links to work but it's getting complicated. Keep in mind that in Javascript the event system works by bubbling. The most deep object will get the click event, and then if it can handle it, it will handle it. When handling the event, it can prevent it to go further and the event will not propagate further. If it decide not to block the event, it will go to the parent element and so on until it reaches the HTML element.

If the element cannot handle an event, it will go to the parent automatically until if finds one element that can handle the event. If no element can handle the event, then it will not get handled. I suggest you to read more about it on the w3c website.

http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Thanks for far ;) But how do I go about 'implementing' this?
Should I put this code in a .js file and call it?

The click event has to be applied to the <section> encapsulating it all. So when I click anywhere on the <section> I will be redirected to the link retrieved from the script.

Comment: You're question isn't clear about that. You can add this code almost anywhere in a script tag or in a js file. It doesn't really matter. What matters is that it will get called after the html document is ready. Habitually you can just add the script at the end and it will work but I'd recommend using something like `requirejs`.

Comment: I can't get it to function? I've put your code in a .js file which is loaded OK. But I don't see the event when clicking on the link?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know this can be done cause I've seen it on another site. 
I still can't get it to function right. :(

Comment: No errors - I've tried to add the script into the code with the <script> tags - same result

Comment: Can it be because of multi <section> tags 'above' the one I'm trying to target? Maybe if we add a class (author) to this specific section?

Comment: BTW, you can use `var links = document.links` to get just the [links](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-links) and ignore any anchors.

Comment: I've tried to update the var links to target the specific anchor.
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a.profile-link');

Won't this do the trick aswell?

Comment: This is the string i get in the Event window in FireBug from the site I'm trying to get this function from.

function (a){return typeof f!="undefined"&&(!a||f.event.triggered!==a.type)?f.event.dispatch.apply(i.elem,arguments):b}

Does anybody understand this? That string is what makes it work.
I've just copied the entire js over and it works on my site.
Bur I would like to isolate this particular function since the original file is huge.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what u ask is that you don't know what the first anchorTag link is it may be any value but It will return the href value.
this is the code:

```
 <script>
let a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for(i=0; i < a.length; i++){
if(i==0){
 console.log(a[i].href);
["touchstart","mousedown"].forEach(e=>{
a[I].addEventListener(e,()=>{
alert(a[I]);
});
});
}
}
</script>
```